# Docker config for postgress and pgadmin fails

Tags: postgresql, docker

I have the next yml file:

```
version: '3.5'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    container_name: postgres
    volumes:
      - ./pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
      - '5432:5432'

  pgadmin:
    image: dpage/pgadmin4
    restart: always
    container_name: nest-pgadmin4
    environment:
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=admin@admin.com
      - PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=pgadmin4
    ports:
      - '5050:80'
    depends_on:
      - db
```

[image]
When i do `docker compose up` i expect to run both images, but i get both continously restarting in Docker app.  When i also open http://localhost:5050/, the tab is not opeing.
Did someone faced the same issue? 
 Note: i use Windows and try to run the dosker file in context of nest js application.

Comment: I managed to run your ```docker-compose.yml``` successfully.  Can you share any logs that could help us troubleshoot all of this ?

Comment: @ABWassim Dis you manage to run the pgadmin url?

Comment: Yes, successfully landed on the pgadmin interface, and connected with the email/password. Again, can you share any error logs you can find ?

Comment: i updated the question with an image, also i get this in console nest-pgadmin4  | exec /entrypoint.sh: exec format error
and postgres       | exec /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: exec format error

Comment: Mmm ... This usually indicates an architecture incompatibility ... Can you run ```docker image inspect postgres``` and give me the value of "Architecture" ? Can you also indicate what kind of processor architecture you have on your host machine ?

Comment: "Architecture": "amd64", but my processor is OSArchitecture  
64-bit

Comment: Can you run `docker system prune --all` to clear everything, and then run the `docker-compose up` command again ? Also is it the first time something like this happens ? Did you always run your container successfully ?